# how to arrange numbers in ascending order based on a column data

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with 3 columns. 2 columns have data - msisdn and cardnumber, but one column is empty - accountnumber

```
MSISDN, CARDNUMBER AND ACCOUNTNUMBER
```

I am trying to add data in the accountnumber column. The value here is Min 1 and Max 4.
[image: this is the current data i have in the excel file]

so if an msisdn has 2 cardnumbers registered, his accountnumbers will be 1,2 and the next msisdn in the next row will have 1 for his first cardnumber.

i have 10,000 rows and i cannot update all of them manually. please if someone can help me with a formula i would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below formula in B2 and copy that cell and paste in all other rows in B

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A2=A2)*1)
```

Comment: This formula just gives the number of matches found from row two till the current row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula on column B

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```